# intellij не создает web.xml

Tags: java, intellij-idea

при попытке создания web application, intellij не предлагает создать WEB-INF директорию и web.xml
[image: вот что выдает ide]

Comment: было похожее, но мне даже лень вопрос было задавать. Просто сам создавал и все.

Comment: http://info.javarush.ru/fatfaggy/2017/10/28/Создание-простейшего-web-проекта-в-intellij-idea-enterprise-edition-Пошагово-с-картинками.html здесь описание. посмотрите часть в которой описывается "Web Application". p.s. В целом это все можно добавить руками, папку и файл web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас IDEA Ultimate edition, то после создания проекта можно сделать [так](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-web-application-support.html):
Project Structure <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S</kbd> -> Facets -> Web -> Deployment descriptors -> Add <kbd>Alt+Insert</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Альтернативный вариант - создать шаблон файла `web.xml` и генерировать по нему файлы в проекте при необходимости (но папку `WEB-INF` придется создавать вручную).

**UPD:** в IDEA уже есть готовые шаблоны - находятся в разделе `Other` -> `Web` -> `Deployment descriptors`